# Enlarge UIButton text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I use Masonry library to create Auto Layout constraints programmatically. Here is my code for creating UIButton:

```
readNext = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
readNext.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth   = YES;
readNext.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping;
[readNext setTitle:@"Читать дальше" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:readNext];


[readNext mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {


make.width.equalTo(@160);
make.height.equalTo(@80);
make.right.equalTo(newsContainerView.mas_right).with.offset(-20);
make.bottom.equalTo(newsContainerView.mas_bottom).with.offset(-20);

}];
```

Basically its mean that i create button that aligned to right and bot of view, and width of that button is 160 points, and height is 80. However, the label text font is too small. Even when i expand width or height (or both) its no changing. How to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no property available to increase font size as frame size increases.

> adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth is a Boolean value indicating whether the font size should be reduced in order to fit the title string into the label’s bounding rectangle.

What you can probably do is set font of `titleLabel` to some large value say 100 and set `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to true. Thus that will make your font size shrink automatically so that text adjusts in the given frame size.

Comment: readNext.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:28];
 helped.